# Error with Ionic2 RC0 loading external modules

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng-modules, angular2-aot

In Ionic 2 RC0, I have a problem with angular2-text-mask "1.0.1", I think this is a problem with AoT and most of the external modules though.

In dev mode, I got this error:

`bundle dev failed:  Module /root/path/node_modules/angular2-text-mask/dist/angular2TextMask.js does not export TextMaskModule (imported by /root/path/src/app/app.module.ts)`

So I fixed this overriding `rollup.config.js`

```
commonjs({
    namedExports: {
        'node_modules/angular2-text-mask/dist/angular2TextMask.js': ['TextMaskModule']
    }
}),
```

But I have a problem when trying to build it. So in prod mode:

`ngc: Error: Unexpected value 'TextMaskModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'`

My `app.module` code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        FormsModule,
        TextMaskModule
    ],
    declarations: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it the same error with `ionic build --dev`?